# UITextView textStorage insert issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am inserting an attributed text in UITextView at the last of UITextView. After inserting the attributed text if user type anything that text is also coming as attributed(coming with blue colour). How to fix that.

Comment: Look into the `typingAttributes` property of `UITextView`.

Comment: How to reset the typingAttributes.

Comment: [Search is your friend](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+typingAttributes)